# How to fetch product by a non-existed attribute in magento?

Tags: php, attributes, magento-1.9

I added two simple products and after this I created an attribute "premium" with yes/no options. This is to make the featured product.

After this I created two more products, one with premium yes and another with no respectively.

At this time I can only fetch from the last two products by filtering using the following code :

```
     $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        //->addFieldToFilter('premium',array('notnull' => true))
        ->addFieldToFilter('premium',array('like' => '0')) // "0" for non-premium and "1" for premium products
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'premium'))
        ->load();
 foreach ($products as $product)
              {
                       Zend_Debug::dump($product->name);
                       Zend_Debug::dump($product->price);
                       Zend_Debug::dump($product->premium);
              }
```

output :

```
 string(17) "newtest product 1"

string(9) "4000.0000"

string(1) "0"
```

Now I want to fetch only the first two products.
How can I do this?